# Break down keyword in URL, then check whether the keywords exist in content page

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

1) Can MATLAB break down the key words in URL? 
   eg:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname, 
   output:wikipedia wiki Hostname

2) After the output of keywords in URL then check whether the keywords exist in the content of the page like the content below, if yes then return 1, else return 0

Contents:

Hostname From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In         computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename[1]) is a label that is assigned to a device connected to a computer network and that is used to identify the device in various forms of electronic communication such as the World Wide Web, e-mail or Usenet. Hostnames may be simple names consisting of a single word or phrase, or they may be structured. On the Internet, hostnames may have appended the name of a Domain Name System (DNS) domain, separated from the host-specific label by a period ("dot"). In the latter form, a hostname is also called a domain name.

```
Example of output:
wikipedia [1]
wiki      [0]
Hostname  [1]
```

Comment: How would you tell Matlab that 'en' is not a key word?

Comment: i got think of to eliminate 'en' & 'org' since that are hostname & domain name, there is meaningless to detect the keyword in content. But, there is difficulty to check 1 by 1. If Matlab have these function then that goods. any idea? If cannot then proceed to remain the 'en'&'org', then the output of keyword will be 'wikipedia wiki Hostname,en,org'

Comment: Use `regexp` (as in @Nitish's answer) to separate tokens, or maybe [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html). For the wanted / unwanted key words, you probably need to manually make a list

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname'
Paragraph = 'Hostname From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename[1]) blah blah'
SplitStrings = regexp(str,'[/.]','split')
c = containers.Map;
for it = SplitStrings
c( it{1} ) = strfind(Paragraph, it{1} )
end
```

Issues:

- You will need to find out a way of including relevant and irrelevant parts of the URL. Currently, it takes `http` and `en` as valid parts of string.
- You will need to see if you want the case to be respected or not.
- It is algorithmically inefficient since it is making as many passes through the data as keywords. I will think about improving on this.

Comment: Hi, I have settle part (1)...thx.
how about the part (2)?
2) After the output of keywords in URL then check whether the keywords exist in the content of the page like the content below, if yes then return 1, else return 0